# Get "owner" of an instance

Tags: objective-c, object

So I am pretty new to Objective C (and programming in general) and I have run into a problem. 
Essentially, I have created an array of "trains" and each train has a UIButton instance. Here are the relevant parts of that section
In the view did load:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numTrains; i++) {
    Train *newTrain = [[Train alloc] init];
    UIButton *nButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    //more lines to set frame, background, etc.
    [nButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectTrain:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    newTrain.button = nButton;
    [trainArray addObject:newTrain];
}
```

Later:

```
-(void)selectTrain:(UIButton*)sender {
    //this is where I run into trouble
}
```

I want to find out which train the button belongs to. Is this possible? If so, how is it done?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming `trainArray` is an instance variable: In `selectTrain:`,  for each `Train` in `trainArray`, check if `train.button == sender`, if yes, then this is the train corresponding to the button.

Comment: You could keep an NSMutableDictionary, `buttonDictionary`, which contains entries for each button as the key and the train as the corresponding value.  A minor PITA to maintain, though.

Comment: Do keep in mind that if this "array" is being represented as a TableView then the buttons will be deleted by the system as the corresponding cells pass out of view.  Not a problem for a scroll view, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ideas come to mind.

1)  You can set the tag property on the button when you create it.

```
nButton.tag = i;
```

The train will be

```
[trainArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
```

2) You can loop through trainArray to find the Train object that contains that particular button

```
Train *trainWithButton;

for(Train *t in trainArray){
    if t.button == sender{
        trianWithButton = t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this would be to give button a `tag`. Then in your `selectTrain:` method, you can cast the `sender` object to a UIButton (`UIButton *trainButton = (UIButton *)sender`) and get the tag with `trainButton.tag`. You will then want to assign the `tag` with some unique property from your Train object. Since you have an array for your trains (`trainArray`) just use the index of the train for the button tag. You for loop will then look like this...

```
for (int i = 0; i < numTrains; i++) {
    Train *newTrain = [[Train alloc] init];
    UIButton *nButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    //more lines to set frame, background, etc.
    [nButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectTrain:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    newTrain.button = nButton;
    button.tag = i;
    [trainArray addObject:newTrain];
}
```

And the button action method...

```
- (void)selectTrain:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIButton *trainButton = (UIButton *)sender
    Train *theTrain = trainArray[trainButton.tag];
}
```